# Как в QtQuick добавить несколько классов?

Tags: qtcreator, qml, qtquick

Есть проект со связкой QML для интерфейса и С++ кодом для емких задач. Как связать между собой один класс с QML я знаю. Но и в этом же проекте будет ещё один класс, который должен быть связан с QML.

Проще говоря: есть класс который работает с отдельным устройством и этот класс соединяется с QML. Теперь плюсуется ещё один класс, который прошивает это устройство. А как второй класс соединить - ума не приложу.

Может кто-то сталкивался?

Вот мой main.cpp файл

```
//#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>

#include <QQmlContext>
#include "backend.h"
//#include "firmware_update"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
//qSetMessagePattern("%{file}(%{line}): %{message}");

QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);
//QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

QCoreApplication::setOrganizationName("company");
QCoreApplication::setApplicationName("name");

QApplication app(argc, argv);

QQmlApplicationEngine engine;

BackEnd backend;
//  Firmware_update updateFirmware;

QQmlContext *context = engine.rootContext();

qmlRegisterUncreatableType<Modbus_master>("MKPConfig", 1, 0, "ModMaster", "c++ type"); // для флагов
context->setContextProperty("modMaster", &backend);
//  context->setContextProperty("updateFirmware", &updateFirmware);

engine.load(QUrl(QLatin1String("qrc:/main.qml")));

return app.exec();
}
```

Comment: Не понял проблему. Вы сделали класс `Modbus_Master` доступным из qml-кода с помощью функции `qmlRegisterUncreatableType`. Что мешает применить эту же функцию для второго класса? Если нужно будет создавать объект этого класса, воспользуйтесь функцией `qmlRegisterType`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я немного по другому решил свою проблему:

```
#include "firmware.h"
firmware firmware;
QQmlContext *context = engine.rootContext();
context->setContextProperty("updateFirmware", &firmware);
```

Без `qmlRegisterUncreatableType`